# Do Sonic tanks cause Friendly Fire?

Tags: dune-2

The Atreides Special Unit, the Sonic tank fires a wave of sound forward which damages all units in its wake. Can this unit cause widespread damage to my own base and my own units like the rocket tanks?

Comment: Are you referring to Dune 2 on DOS or remake Dune 2000?

Comment: Dune2 Dos, otherwise the tag would have been dune2000

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if your unit is in line of fire between Sonic Tank and target, your units will take damage. Exception is other Sonic Tanks. They are not damaged by Sonic Waves.

Source(s):

- http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Dune_II:_The_Building_of_a_Dynasty/Units#Atreides
- Personal experience

Comment: Btw, in Dune 2000 and Emperor: Battle for Dune they cause friendly fire too

Comment: Hand't played either of those for a long time, so my memory is little bit fuzzy, though I do remember that they did cause FF in Emperor... now I want to play them...

Comment: To be more clear: Sonic Tanks damage everything, enemies and friends alike, that's not another ST. ST is immune to other STs, both friends and enemies. So when Ordos turn one of your STs, just give it another ST to fire at. They'll just sit there harmlessly while you wait for the effect to wear out : )